# paho-mqtt subscribe check subscription status

Tags: python-2.7, mqtt, paho

I am using [paho-mqtt 1.2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/paho-mqtt/1.2) in python2.7 to listen to messages broadcasted by a broker, after subscribing to specific topics.

It's initialized like

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt    #python mqtt package

# initialize MQTT client
mqttc = mqtt.Client()

# register listener functions    
mqttc.on_connect   = on_connect
mqttc.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
mqttc.on_message   = on_message

# connect to MQTT broker
mqttc.connect(<IP>, <PORT>, <KEEPALIVE_INTERVAL>)

# subscribe a topic to the broker
subscr = mqttc.subscribe(<TOPIC_NAME>, 0)
```

with the custom functions

```
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print "connected"

def on_subscribe(client, userdata, mid, granted_qos):
    print "subscribed"

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print "message received"
```

From the API I can read about the subscribe() function

*The function returns a tuple (result, mid), where result is
MQTT_ERR_SUCCESS to indicate success or (MQTT_ERR_NO_CONN, None) if the
client is not currently connected.  mid is the message ID for the
subscribe request. The mid value can be used to track the subscribe
request by checking against the mid argument in the on_subscribe()
callback if it is defined.*

I am now trying to retrieve a status about the subscription, i.e. if I subscribed a VALID topic. In my understanding, the subscribe() function only returns an error code, if the topic has an invalid format. But I want to extract information, if I subscribed to a topic which is ACTUALLY broadcasted.

So far I get an on_subscribe() call including a subscription ID, no matter which topic (valid or invalid) I subscribe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always subscribe to all (syntactically correct) topics, because a message may be published to it at some point in the future.

In MQTT there is no need to declare a topic before using it, a broker will allow you to subscribe to a topic that a message has never (and may be never will) had a message published to.

Topics effectively only exist at the moment a message is published to that topic.

The only way to know what topics are actually being used is to subscribe to them and see if a message turns up.

Comment: So this means if I have a topic, which broadcasts message only once a day, and I have a typo in my topic subscription, I will not notice this for one day?

Comment: Assuming a new client with no persistent subscriptions and the message is being published without the retained flag set, then yet, you will only receive the message when it's published

Comment: Since I am only configuring the listener, not the broker, I was not aware of the `retained=True` option, but this will definitely give me a handle on this issue, thanks!

Comment: The retained flag is a property of a published message, not something you configure on the broker

Comment: Ok, but this still means that I, as listener, can not configure this (neither the broker, nor how messages are published), correct?

Comment: If you are only implementing the subscriber, then yes, you have no control of this